# WPF Binding, always create new object

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

In my model, I have the following property

```
public List<IColumnElement> MenuItems
{
  get
  {
    return new List<IColumnElement>() { new Table(), new FieldSet() };
  }
}
```

It is bound as `Itemssource` to a context menu and creates two elements "Table" and "FieldSet". If the element is clicked, the bound object shall be added to a collection. However the bound List is only generated once and always returns the same two objects....

Is there a good solution to make the binding always return new objects for `Table` and `FieldSet` ?

Comment: That code is creating a new list anytime the getter is invoked, which is not ideal. Make a private property instead, and in the getter do a check that `if (_list == null) _list = new List<IColumnElement>() { new Table(), new FieldSet() };`, and then you can `return _list` so it will only be created once

Comment: @Rachel no its the other way round. I need a new object each time I click on the context menu entry, but it seems the binding only creates the `List` the fist time it is bound, so always returns the same object.

Comment: Oh ok, I see... in that case you might want to use an `ICommand` to trigger on click which re-creates the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF Binding generally occurs in response to change. When you first start up, the property is initially bound (the one time you see it), but until your code tells WPF that the property has changed, it's won't check again.

The way to tell WPF that the property has changed is through implementing [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx). Your class containing `MenuItems` would implement that interface, and then when you want WPF to call your getter again, you would invoke the `PropertyChanged` event, passing in the property name as a parameter.

As a matter of convenience, usually you would implement a base class that provide the interface, and a method such as

```
internal void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
         PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

You would then call `RaisePropertyChanged("MenuItems");` in order to trigger a binding update.

As a side note, I would consider adjusting your design to just having the context menu list options, and have your code behind/view model take care of constructing the requisite objects when the corresponding option is chosen from the context menu.

Comment: Great, calling `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(MenuItems))` generates/binds a new object each time.

Comment: Oh how I look forward to getting to use `nameof` some day... Hardcoded strings kill me, but I'm stuck on .NET 4 =(